# setNeedsDisplay not updating interface

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

When calling [polygonShapeView setNeedsDisplay]; my polygonShapeView drawRect method is NOT called. I am able to do polygonShapeView.hidden = YES, which works fine so I have a good reference to the view and have hooked up my outlet. Any ideas?

Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PolygonShape.h"
#import "PolygonShapeView.h"

@interface Controller : NSObject {
    IBOutlet UIButton *decreaseButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *increaseButton;
    IBOutlet UILabel *numberOfSidesLabel;
    IBOutlet PolygonShape *polygonShape;
    IBOutlet PolygonShapeView *polygonShapeView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *polygonLabel; 
}
- (IBAction)decrease:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)increase:(id)sender;
- (void)awakeFromNib;
- (void)updateInterface;
@end
```

Controller.m

```
//
//  Controller.m
//
//  Created by Chris Muench on 6/24/11.
//  Copyright 2011 N/A. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller
- (IBAction)decrease:(id)sender 
{
    [polygonShape setNumberOfSides:numberOfSidesLabel.text.integerValue - 1];
    [self updateInterface];
}

- (IBAction)increase:(id)sender 
{
    [polygonShape setNumberOfSides:numberOfSidesLabel.text.integerValue + 1];
    [self updateInterface];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    polygonShape = [[PolygonShape alloc] initWithNumberOfSides:numberOfSidesLabel.text.integerValue minimumNumberOfSides:3 maximumNumberOfSides:12];
    [self updateInterface];
}
- (void)updateInterface 
{
    [polygonShapeView setNeedsDisplay];
    numberOfSidesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",polygonShape.numberOfSides];
    polygonLabel.text = polygonShape.name; 

    if (polygonShape.numberOfSides == polygonShape.maximumNumberOfSides)
    {
        increaseButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        increaseButton.enabled = YES;
    }

    if(polygonShape.numberOfSides == polygonShape.minimumNumberOfSides)
    {
        decreaseButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        decreaseButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only *guess*, but it seems your `polygonShapeView` is not linked in any way to the `polygonShape`. So it might draw, but not according to the data you expect.

I think there should be something like `polygonShapeView.shape = polygonShape;` in `awakeFromNib`, or in `updateInterface`.

Comment: It turned out I was making a new polygonShape in the awakeFromNib instead of using the one I created inside the nib, which caused nothing to really change.

Comment: Exactly, hence *not connected*. :)